# $lookup with nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My document  has array with multiple objects, And I need to find related values and push into same array.

**CART**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b72119fbb60750e0061b9"),
    "cartId" : "1529573905701",
    "supplierId" : ObjectId("5b221d1b63eda2902418434d"),
    "user_id" : "5b20c54651e68057b3cbe745",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-21T09:38:25.680Z"),
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "21-06-2018",
            "timeSlot_id" : ObjectId("5b29e08cb116c31f5b1f56c6"),
            "time" : "03:30 PM - 04:30 PM",
            "serviceId" : ObjectId("5b24aff4abf2494701bc1c15"),
            "cost" : 250,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b72119fbb60750e0061ba")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b72329fbb60750e0061bb"),
            "cost" : 250,
            "serviceId" : ObjectId("5b24aff4abf2494701bc1c15"),
            "time" : "03:30 PM - 04:30 PM",
            "timeSlot_id" : ObjectId("5b29e08cb116c31f5b1f56c6"),
            "date" : "21-06-2018"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**SERVICES**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b24aff4abf2494701bc1c15"),
    "isActivated" : true,
    "supplierServiceId" : 900146649,
    "serviceId" : 99473640,
    "serviceName" : "AC Reparing",
    "description" : "all type of AC, Split AC and Window AC",
    "cost" : 250,
    "serviceDuration" : "60",
    "startTime" : "07:00 AM",
    "endTime" : "08:30 PM",
    "supplierId" : "5b221d1b63eda2902418434d",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-16T06:36:36.091Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**TIMESLOTS**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b29e08cb116c31f5b1f56c6"),
    "displayString" : "03:30 PM - 04:30 PM",
    "isActivated" : true,
    "startTime" : "15:30 PM",
    "endTime" : "16:30 PM",
    "duration" : "60",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-20T05:05:16.405Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Inside the services in **CART** there are two values **serviceId** and **timeSlot_id**

*I need data related to both from related collections. Within same object.

Mongo version -v3.6.5

Please Help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `services` in order to match its `timeSlot_id` and `serviceId` with the `_id` of another collection of TimeSlots and `ServiceId` respectively... And then you can [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) it to start the process of "rolling back" into the arrays.

If you have mongodb version **3.6**

```
Cart.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "user_id": _user._id } },
  { "$unwind": "$services" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": TimeSlot.collection.name,
    "let": { "timeSlot_id": "$services.timeSlot_id" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$timeSlot_id" ] } } }
     ],
     "as": "services.timeSlot_id"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Service.collection.name,
    "let": { "serviceId": "$services.serviceId" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$serviceId" ] } } }
     ],
     "as": "services.serviceId"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$services.timeSlot_id" },
  { "$unwind": "$services.serviceId" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "services": { "$push": "$services" },
    "cartId" : { "$first": "$cartId" },
    "supplierId" : { "$first": "$supplierId" },
    "user_id" : { "$first": "$user_id" },
    "createdAt" : { "$first": "$createdAt" }
  }}
])
```

If you have mongodb version prior to **3.6**

```
Cart.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "user_id": _user._id } },
  { "$unwind": "$services" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": TimeSlot.collection.name,
    "localField": "services.timeSlot_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "services.timeSlot_id",
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Service.collection.name,
    "localField": "services.serviceId",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "services.serviceId",
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$services.timeSlot_id" },
  { "$unwind": "$services.serviceId" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "services": { "$push": "$services" },
    "cartId" : { "$first": "$cartId" },
    "supplierId" : { "$first": "$supplierId" },
    "user_id" : { "$first": "$user_id" },
    "createdAt" : { "$first": "$createdAt" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hey @Ashh I upvoted your solution, its really helpful for me. But I would like to add a scenario here, so let say if serviceId is optional, in that case what will happen is, it will return only those array elements who has both serviceId & timeSlot_id, So do you have any solution for that? How can we overcome this and should be able to return all the array elements even if any key is optional and not available inside object.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex-and-preservenullandemptyarrays.... Use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` on `$unwind`